# Input field added through javascript not in PHP $_POST variable. How to fix this?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form inside an html table.

I am dynamically adding input fields to a form through jquery. When I took var dump while submitting the form, the $_POST array does not have the added fields. Why is it happening?

Here is how my js looks like:

```
$('#add-more-del-areas').live('click',function(e){
        var del_area_count = $('[name=number_of_delivery_areas]').val();
        var new_count = (parseInt(del_area_count)+1);
        var tr_html =   '<tr>'+
                            '<td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Delivery Area '+new_count+'</strong></td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<input  name="d_area'+new_count+'" type="text"  size="50"  value=""/>'+
                                '<div class="area-display-container" id="test'+new_count+'-display"></div>'+
                                '<div>'+
                                    '<input class="auto-suggest-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="test'+new_count+'"/>'+
                                    '<div class="test-content" id="test'+new_count+'-content"></div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</td>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                        '<tr id="del_area-'+new_count+'" bgcolor="#FF9933">'+
                            '<td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Dilivery charges for area '+new_count+'</strong></td>'+
                            '<td><input name="m_order'+new_count+'" type="text" size="50" value="0"></td>'+
                        '</tr>';
        //$('#del_area-'+del_area_count).after(tr_html);
        $(tr_html).insertAfter('#del_area-'+del_area_count);

        big_cms.auto_suggest_({id: 'test'+new_count,input_field: 'd_area'+new_count});
        $('[name=number_of_delivery_areas]').val(new_count);
        e.preventDefault();

    });
```

Though html is pathetic and too long still, here it is:

```
<table width="840" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: #57414D 4px Solid; margin:auto;">
            <tr>
                <td  height="20px" bgcolor="#57414D" align="center" colspan="2"><span  style="font-family:arial; font-size:13px; color:#ffffff"><b>You can add/edit Restaurant/Management content here!!</b></span></td>
            </tr>
            <?php   
                if ($bgclass == "bgExtraLightGray")
                    $bgclass = "bgWhite";
                else
                    $bgclass = "bgExtraLightGray";      
            ?>
            <form name="frmCatPopup" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return ValidateContactForm();">
            <tr align="center" bgcolor="#FF9933" class="<?php echo($bgclass); ?>">
                <td colspan="2" class="note">&nbsp;<?php echo($errMsg); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="40%" class="heading1" style="padding-left:10px"><strong>Register Name</strong></td>
                <td width="60%" style="padding-bottom:4px;"><select name="name" class="restar_txtbox" style="width:326px;">
                <?php

                    $quer_l="select * from ".$tableprefix."restaurant_sign_up";
                    $cmd_l=mysql_query($quer_l);
                    while($res_l=mysql_fetch_array($cmd_l))
                    {               
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $res_l['fld_id']; ?>" <?php if($rs['signup_id']==$res_l['fld_id']) echo"selected";?>><?php echo $res_l['fld_contact_person']; ?></option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#FF9933">  
                <td width="40%" class="heading1" style="padding-left:10px"><strong>Restaurant Name</strong></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="rest_name" size="50" value="<?php echo $rs['fld_name'];?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="heading1" style="padding:4px 0 4px 10px;"><strong>Address</strong></td>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 0;">
                    <textarea rows="3" cols="38" name="address"  id="address"   value="<?php echo($rs["fld_address"]); ?>" size="50">
                        <?php echo($rs["fld_address"]); ?>
                    </textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#FF9933">
                <td class="heading1" style="padding-left:10px"><strong>Location</strong></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="loc" style="width:326px;" ><!--onchange="locat(this.value)"-->
                        <option>Select Location</option> 
                        <?php
                            $quer_l="select * from ".$tableprefix."location where location_status='1'";
                            $cmd_l=mysql_query($quer_l);
                            while($res_l=mysql_fetch_array($cmd_l))
                            {               
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $res_l['location_id']; ?>" <?php if($rs['location_id']==$res_l['location_id']) echo"selected";?>><?php echo $res_l['name']; ?></option>
                        <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 10px;"><strong>Area</strong></td>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 0;">

                    <?php /*?><div id="area"><select name="area" style="width:326px;">
                        <option value="asap">Select Location First</option>
                        </select>
                        </div><?php */?>
                        <select name="area"  style="width:326px;">
                    <?php
                        $quer_a="select * from ".$tableprefix."area where status='1'";
                        $cmd_a=mysql_query($quer_a);
                        while($res_a=mysql_fetch_array($cmd_a))
                        {               
                    ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $res_a['area_id']; ?>"  <?php if($rs['area_id']==$res_a['area_id']) echo"selected";?>><?php echo $res_a['area_name']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                        </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#FF9933">
                <td style="padding-left:10px"><strong>Opening Time</strong></td>
                <td><input name="openingtime_start" type="text"  id="openingtime_start"  value="
                <?php 
                    $q1=$rs["fld_openingtime_start"];
                    $q=strlen($rs["fld_openingtime_start"]);
                    $S=substr("$q1","-$q","-2");
                    $S4=substr("$q1","-2","2");
                    echo $S;
                ?>">
                    <select name="start">
                        <option value="am" <?php if($S4=="am"){echo "selected";}?>>am</option>
                        <option value="pm" <?php if($S4=="pm"){echo "selected";}?>>pm</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 10px;"><strong>Closing Time</strong></td>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 0;">
                    <input name="closingtime_start" type="text" class="restar_txtbox" id="closingtime_start"  value="
                    <?php 
                        $q6=$rs["fld_closingtime_start"];
                        $q7=strlen($rs["fld_closingtime_start"]);
                        $S3=substr("$q6","-$q7","-2");
                        $S4=substr("$q6","-2","2");
                        echo $S3;
                    ?>">
                    <select name="end">
                        <option value="am"<?php if($S4=="am"){echo "selected";}?>>am</option>
                        <option value="pm" <?php if($S4=="pm"){echo "selected";}?>>pm</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#FF9933">
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 10px;"><strong>Opening Time</strong></td>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 0;">
                    <input name="openingtime_start1" type="text" class="restar_txtbox" id="openingtime_start1"  value="
                    <?php
                        $q4=$rs["fld_openingtime_start1"];
                        $q5=strlen($rs["fld_openingtime_start1"]);
                        $S2=substr("$q4","-$q5","-2");
                        $S4=substr("$q4","-2","2");
                        echo $S2;
                    ?>">
                    <select name="start1">
                        <option value="am" <?php if($S4=="am"){echo "selected";}?>>am</option>
                        <option value="pm" <?php if($S4=="pm"){echo "selected";}?>>pm</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 10px;"><strong>Closing Time</strong></td>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 0;">
                    <input name="closingtime_start1" type="text" class="restar_txtbox" id="closingtime_start1"  value="
                <?php 
                    $q2=$rs["fld_closingtime_start1"];
                    $q3=strlen($rs["fld_closingtime_start1"]);
                    $S1=substr("$q2","-$q3","-2");
                    $S4=substr("$q4","-2","2");
                    echo $S1;
                ?>">
                    <select name="end1">
                        <option value="am" <?php if($S4=="am"){echo "selected";}?>>am</option>
                        <option value="pm" <?php if($S4=="pm"){echo "selected";}?>>pm</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#FF9933">
                <td style="padding-left:10px"><strong>Delivery Fee</strong></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text"    name="delivery_fee" value="<?php echo($rs["fld_deliveryfee"]); ?>" size="50">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 10px;"><strong>Cuisines</strong></td>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 0;">
                    <select name="cuisines[]" id="cuisines[]"  style="width:326px;" multiple="multiple">
                    <?php
                        $quer_l="select * from ".$tableprefix."cuisines where status='1'";
                        $cmd_l=mysql_query($quer_l);
                        $allCuisines = array();
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($cmd_l))
                        {
                            $allCuisines[] = $row;
                        }                 
                        //[BIG-3] In case there are multiple cuisines selected, they were not being pulled back from DB for display at frontend. 
                        $cuisineIds = explode(',',$rs['fld_cuisines']);               // In the $cuisineIds, all the cuisines selected from DB get stored
                        foreach( $allCuisines as  $res_l)                            //Looping on all cuisines as they all need to be echoed once, as well as comparing the condition for a match to the Cuisines originally associated with restaurant
                        {
                        ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $res_l['cuisines_id']; ?>" 
                            <?php  
                                foreach ( $cuisineIds  as $cuisId ) 
                                {
                                    if($cuisId ==$res_l['cuisines_id'])
                                        echo"selected"; 
                                }
                            ?> >
                            <?php echo $res_l['cuisines_name'];   ?></option>                
                            <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-left:10px"><strong>Pure Veg</strong></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox"     name="veg_flag" 
                    <?php 
                        if(isSet($rs["veg_flag"]) && $rs['veg_flag']==1) 
                            echo("checked='checked'"); 
                    ?> value="1"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
                <!--</td>   </tr> -->
            <tr bgcolor="#FF9933">
                <td style="padding-left:10px"><strong>Min Order</strong></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text"     name="min_order" value="
                    <?php echo($rs["fld_minorder"]); ?>" size="50"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 10px;"><strong>Phone</strong></td>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 0;"><input name="phone" type="text"  id="phone" size="50"  value="<?php echo($rs["fld_phone"]); ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#FF9933">
                <td style="padding-left:10px"><strong>Upload 1</strong></td>
                <td><input name="photos" type="file" size="38" id="photos"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 10px;"><strong>upload 2</strong></td>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 0;"><input name="videos" type="file" id="videos"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#FF9933">
                <td style="padding-left:10px"><strong>Rating</strong></td>
                <td><input name="rating" type="text" id="rating"   value="<?php echo($rs["fld_rating"]); ?>" size="50"></td>
            </tr>
                <!--</td></tr> -->
            <tr bgcolor="#fff001">
                <td class="heading1" style="padding-left:10px"><strong>Restaurent Close Day</strong></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="day" style="width:200px;" ><!--onchange="locat(this.value)"-->
                        <option value="0">Select Day</option>
                        <option  value="1">Monday</option>
                        <option  value="2">Tuesday</option>
                        <option  value="3">Wednesday</option>
                        <option  value="4">Thursday</option>
                        <option  value="5">Friday</option>
                        <option  value="6">Saturday</option>
                        <option  value="7">Sunday</option>                
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 10px;"><strong>Description</strong></td>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 0;"><textarea name="desc" type="text" id="desc" cols="38" rows="3"   ><?php echo($rs["fld_desc"]); ?></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#FF9933">
                <td style="padding-left:10px"><strong>Info</strong></td>
                <td><textarea name="info" type="text" id="info" cols="38" rows="3"  > <?php echo($rs["fld_info"]); ?></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 10px;"><strong>Specilialities</strong></td>
                <td style="padding:4px 0 4px 0;"><input type="text"   name="specialities" value="<?php echo($rs['fld_specialities']) ?>" size="50" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#FF9933" >
                <td style="padding-left:10px"><strong>Delivery Time</strong></td>
                <td><input name="delivery_time" type="text" id="delivery_time" size="50"     value="<?php echo($rs["fld_deliverytime"]); ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>      
                <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Tax</strong></td>
                <td><input name="tax" type="text" id="tax" size="50"  value="<?php echo($rs["fld_tax"]); ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#FF9933">
                <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Cost For One</strong></td>
                <td><input name="cost" type="text" id="cost" size="50" value="<?php echo($rs["fld_cost"]); ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-left:10px"><strong>Packaging Charge</strong></td>
                <td><input name="p_charge" type="text" size="50" value="<?php echo($rs["p_charge"]); ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#FF9933">
                <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Label for Tax</strong></td>
                <td><input name="label_t" type="text" size="50" value="<?php echo($rs["label_t"]); ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
                if(isset($_GET['fld']))
                {
                    $delivery_area_data = Task::getDeliveryAreaData($_GET['fld']);
                    $no_of_del_areas = sizeof($delivery_area_data);
                    if($no_of_del_areas > 0)
                    {
                        echo '<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="number_of_delivery_areas" value="'.$no_of_del_areas.'"/></td></tr>';
                        for($i=1;$i<=$no_of_del_areas;$i++)
                        {
                            $min_id = $i;
                            $min_order = $delivery_area_data[$i]['min_order'];
                            $area_id_str = implode(',',$delivery_area_data[$i]['area_ids']);
                            $area_name_str = '';
                            $j = 0;
                            foreach($delivery_area_data[$i]['area_names'] as $name)
                            {
                                $tmp_area_id = $delivery_area_data[$i]['area_ids'][$j];
                                $area_name_str .= '<span class="area-label" id="test'.$min_id.'-area-'.$tmp_area_id.'">
                                    '.$name.'
                                    <span class="test'.$min_id.'-delete-area delete-x" id="delete-area-'.$tmp_area_id.'">X</span>
                                </span>';
                                $j++;
                            }
                            echo '<tr>
                                    <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Delivery Area '.$min_id.'</strong></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input  name="d_area'.$min_id.'" type="text"  size="50" autocomplete="off" value="'.$area_id_str.'"/>
                                        <div class="area-display-container" id="test'.$min_id.'-display">'.$area_name_str.'</div>
                                        <div>
                                            <input class="auto-suggest-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="test'.$min_id.'"/><br/>
                                            <div class="test-content" id="test'.$min_id.'-content"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr id="del_area-'.$min_id.'" bgcolor="#FF9933">
                                    <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Dilivery charges for area '.$min_id.'</strong></td>
                                    <td><input name="m_order'.$min_id.'" type="text" size="50" value="'.$min_order.'"></td>
                                </tr>
                                ';
                        }
                        echo '<tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <button id="add-more-del-areas">Add more</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Delivery Area 1</strong></td>
                            <td>

                                <input  name="d_area1" type="text"  size="50" autocomplete="off" value=""/>
                                <div class="area-display-container" id="test1-display"></div>
                                <div>
                                    <input class="auto-suggest-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="test1"/><br/>
                                    <div class="test-content" id="test1-content"></div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="#FF9933">
                            <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Dilivery charges for area 1</strong></td>
                            <td><input name="m_order1" type="text" size="50" value=""/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Dilivery area 2</strong></td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="d_area2" type="text" size="50" value=""/>
                                <div class="area-display-container" id="test2-display"></div>
                                <div>
                                    <input class="auto-suggest-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="test2"/>
                                    <div class="test-content" id="test2-content"></div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr bgcolor="#FF9933">
                            <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Dilivery charges for area 2</strong></td>
                            <td><input name="m_order2" type="text" size="50" value=""/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >  
                            <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Dilivery area 3</strong></td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="d_area3" type="text" size="50" value=""/>
                                <div class="area-display-container" id="test3-display"></div>
                                <div>
                                    <input class="auto-suggest-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="test3"/><br/>
                                    <div class="test-content" id="test3-content"></div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>



                        <tr id="del_area-3" bgcolor="#FF9933">                  
                            <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Dilivery charges for area 3</strong></td>
                            <td><input name="m_order3" type="text" size="50" value=""/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <button id="add-more-del-areas">Add more</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                <?php
                    }

                }
                else
                {    
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Delivery Area 1</strong></td>
                        <td>

                            <input  name="d_area1" type="text"  size="50" autocomplete="off" value=""/>
                            <div class="area-display-container" id="test1-display"></div>
                            <div>
                                <input class="auto-suggest-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="test1"/><br/>
                                <div class="test-content" id="test1-content"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr bgcolor="#FF9933">
                        <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Dilivery charges for area 1</strong></td>
                        <td><input name="m_order1" type="text" size="50" value="<?php //echo($rs["m_order1"]); ?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Dilivery area 2</strong></td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="d_area2" type="text" size="50" value=""/>
                            <div class="area-display-container" id="test2-display"></div>
                            <div>
                                <input class="auto-suggest-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="test2"/>
                                <div class="test-content" id="test2-content"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#FF9933">
                        <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Dilivery charges for area 2</strong></td>
                        <td><input name="m_order2" type="text" size="50" value="<?php //echo($rs["m_order2"]); ?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >  
                        <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Dilivery area 3</strong></td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="d_area3" type="text" size="50" value=""/>
                            <div class="area-display-container" id="test3-display"></div>
                            <div>
                                <input class="auto-suggest-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="test3"/><br/>
                                <div class="test-content" id="test3-content"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>



                    <tr id="del_area-3" bgcolor="#FF9933">                  
                        <td style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;"><strong>Dilivery charges for area 3</strong></td>
                        <td><input name="m_order3" type="text" size="50" value="<?php //echo($rs["m_order3"]); ?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button id="add-more-del-areas">Add more</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php 
                }
                ?>


            <tr>
                <td colspan="9" align="center" style="padding-top:5px">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="btnSave" /> &nbsp;
                    <a href="#" onClick="window.close()"><input type="button" value="cancel"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
        </table>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="restar_bottom"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cms.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the new row added inside a form? Could you show HTML?

Comment: ya its inside the form ... pasting the html ....

Comment: the html is too long if i paste it all ... so i pasted the table in which the form lies ....

Comment: The input field probably either doesn't land inside the form, or doesn't have a `name="field_name"`. You can check both with Firebug or Webkit Console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML is invalid.

You cannot have a form inside a `<table>` but outside a `<td>` or `<th>` that is part of that table.

Some browsers error correct by moving the form somewhere it is valid (while leaving all the controls behind).

Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to find this sort of markup error.